# Non-blocking coroutine example

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm just starting learning coroutines and managed to write a simple blocking one, that's aimed on a retry handling of a remote rest service. It returns me an eception if he can't currently handle foo update. But we have an agreement that i'll try to update foo next 10 seconds with an interval of 1 second:

```
private fun updateFoo(fooId: String): Foo {
    val updatedFoo = runBlocking {
        return@runBlocking withTimeoutOrNull(10L) {
            var result: Foo?
            do {
                result = try {
                    fooClient.update(fooId)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    null
                }
                if (result != null) {
                    return@withTimeoutOrNull result
                }
                delay(1L)
            } while (result == null)
            return@withTimeoutOrNull result
        }
    }
    return updatedFoo ?: throw IllegalStateException(
        "Could not update Foo ($fooId) with retries.")
}
```

The point is that i run coroutine blocked. And ten seconds is a big enough interval, so i want to refactor this method to run coroutine nonBlcking.

I've tried to use launch { ... } instead of runBlocking, but i get Job as a result, but that's not what i want, i guess. Could anyone help me to write it correctly???

Comment: Might want to check [async](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basic-jvm.html#async-returning-a-value-from-a-coroutine)

Comment: I think you're mixing up a couple of concepts here and its unclear what you are asking. Do you want `updateFoo` to be non-blocking, or `fooClient.update`? Also, is `fooClient.update` a suspending function?

Comment: i need to call fooClient.update(fooId) in a non-blocking way... fooClient.update is a non suspending function

Comment: You want to call a blocking function from blocking context, using coroutines. All you'll achieve is adding two more layers of indirection to what is ultimately submitting a job to an executor service. You should do it the direct way instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `fooClient.update` is already a suspending function, then your problem really seems to be about how to bridge the non-coroutines world that `updateFoo` lives in (as it is a non-suspending function) with the coroutines world of `fooClient.update`.

If that interpretation of the question is correct, then you'll need to use a traditional mechanism to obtain an async result from `updateFoo`, such as a deferred result or a callback.

If your `updateFoo` code ran in an `async` block you could return the `Deferred<Foo?>` value e.g.:

```
  fun updateFoo(fooId: String): Deferred<Foo?> {
    return GlobalScope.async {
      return@async withTimeoutOrNull(10L) {
        var result: Foo?
        do {
          result = try {
            update(fooId)
          } catch (ex: Exception) {
            null
          }
          if (result != null) {
            return@withTimeoutOrNull result
          }
          delay(1L)
        } while (result == null)
        return@withTimeoutOrNull result
      }
    }
  }
```

and then you could convert that to a `CompletableFuture` in your non-coroutines code e.g.

`asCompletableFuture()`

NOTE: I've used `GlobalScope` here for simplicity buts its generally a good idea to use an explicit scope, depending on your application's requirements.

Your commented that `fooClient.update` is actually a non-suspending blocking function. Given that, you should run it in an appropriate pool of threads that is configured specifically for blocking calls like this, such as `Dispatchers.IO`:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
  update(fooId)
}
```

When run like this, the coroutine will not block -- the `withContext` call suspends.